# ClickOnce publishing

Tags: c#, iis-7, clickonce

I have somme problems understanding publishing clickOnce.

How I have to publish it by visual studio I get, that is just somme filling in.

It is the webserver I don't get. I Have installed IIS on my computer but I don't realy know what I have to do with it. can anyone help me out?

thx

Comment: Do you need a tutorial about ClickOnce deployment? Start reading http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17003/ClickOnce-Quick-steps-to-Deploy-Install-and-Update and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go by doing this is reading a related tutorial.  The main step in this is to enable remote management in IIS.

Here is a great article I made use of.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx